# Interactive Script; Prompt within a loop

Tags: prompt, ksh, interactive

How do I prompt a user for input from a shell script (ksh) within a loop in which a file is read?

The script reads in a file. In each loop pass the user will be asked if he wants to cancel or not? The function works fine outside the loop. Inside the loop, the variable is filled with the line of the file. The script does not stop for interaction.

Any ideas?

**The script:**

```
######################################################
func_yesno(){
echo "cancel y/n?"
read answer
echo Your answer: $answer
case $answer in
  y*|Y*) exit 0 ;;
  n*|N*) echo ok ;;
  *) echo wrong! ;;
esac
}

func_yesno

while read line
do
        echo line: $line
        func_yesno
done < /tmp/in.txt

func_yesno
######################################################
```

**The input file in.txt:**

```
Koeln
Aachen
Muenchen
Hamburg
Berlin
```

**The output:**

```
# /tmp/a.sh
cancel y/n?
n
Your answer: n
ok
line: Koeln
cancel y/n?
Your answer: Aachen
wrong!
line: Muenchen
cancel y/n?
Your answer: Hamburg
wrong!
line: Berlin
cancel y/n?
Your answer:
wrong!
cancel y/n?
n
Your answer: n
ok
```

Answer (score -1):

The function's `read` command is using the same stdin as the while loop's `read`. Use a different file descriptor. Also, the function can be simpler:

```
func_yesno() {
    typeset answer PS3="Cancel (y/n)?"
    select answer in Yes No; do
        case $answer in
            Yes) exit 0 ;;
            No) echo "ok"; break ;;
        esac
    done
}

while read -u3 line; do 
    echo "line: $line"
    func_yesno
done 3< unique.txt
```

Comment: It does, there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: There is no need to nest two while loops.

Comment: Please add your comments to my comments, impossible to follow the conversation in 2 places.